# How to iterate through the words of my text document in shell. I want to display number of words in my text document

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I tried this one, but it is displaying the count on number of lines instead.

```
declare -i x=0 while IFS="" read -r p || [ -n "$p" ] do x=x+1 done <test.txt echo "$x
```

I would be thankful if someone could explain this since i am a beginner

Comment: `wc -w test.txt` ?

Comment: Hi @tkausl. This is working. Thank you soo much. But i want to iterate through the words. Not only count of words. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, post some sample data with expected output to avoid misunderstanding of the question.

Comment: `for i in $(cat file); do something $i; done` instead of using read & redirections is probably the simplest solution

Comment: @Sam `for i in $(cat file)` is a well-known anti-pattern. There is always a better solution than that.

Comment: what would be your prefered solution and why then? i am well aware that the pattern is frequently misused, but to me that alone does not mean it should never be used.

Comment: @Sam, if it contains `*`, you get a list of filenames being iterated over. Why would you ever use it, when there are alternatives that don't have the side effects and bugs? `while read -r -a words; do for word in "${words[@]}"; do ...; done; done <test.txt`

Comment: you have a point in that it was reckless of me to suggest that without a reminder to toggle globbing with `set -f` / `set +f` if there is the slightest possibility the file may contain any special characters.

Comment: do note however that `set -f; for i in $(cat file); do echo $i >/dev/null; done; set +f` times about twice as fast as the equivalent `while read -r -d' ' i; do echo $i >/dev/null; done` for a large file on my system and that the array solution may fail for very long lines.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your words are separated by tabs, spaces ad newlines, the following snippet:

```
echo $'word1 word2! word3
\tword4\t\t\t\t\t\tword5\tword6
word7 word8


word9 word10' | \
while IFS=$'\t ' read -ra linewords; do
    for i in "${linewords[@]}"; do
            echo word is "'$i'"
    done
done
```

will output:

```
word is 'word1'
word is 'word2!'
word is 'word3'
word is 'word4'
word is 'word5'
word is 'word6'
word is 'word7'
word is 'word8'
word is 'word9'
word is 'word10'
```

It uses multiple IFS values combined with `read` reading into an array, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918931/9072753) on how to split a string on a delimeter.

Comment: You chose a convenient input for which your code works :) Try to use a tab between `word5` and `word6` instead of the space. The issue is that you want to use `$'...'` instead of `$"..."`. See [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Locale-Translation) for explanation of `$"..."`. Also, since `read` reads lines by default, the `\n` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use awk for that:

```
$ echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisci elit,
        ..." | 
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        print "iterating " $i
}'
```

Output:

```
iterating Lorem
iterating ipsum
iterating dolor
iterating sit
iterating amet,
iterating consectetur
iterating adipisci
iterating elit,
iterating ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oE '\w+' YOUR_FILE.txt
```

writes the words in YOUR_FILE.txt to standard output. Pipe this into your loop, and you have an iteration over the words.

This assumes that a "word" in your case is one or more characters described by `\w`, i.e. either an underscore or what your current locale defines to be an alphanumeric character. If your idea of a "word" is different, you can of course tailor the regular expression according to your needs.